# Derivative of matrix plus vector from definition

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors

Let $B$ be a matrix $m \times n$. Let   $b\in \Bbb R^m$.
Let $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ be the function defined as $f(x)=Bx+b$.

What is the $Df(x)$(derivative) and how can I find it from the derivative definition?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX!  *Hint*: The differential of an affine function is the associated linear function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
Df(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{B(x+h)+b-Bx-b}{h}=\frac{Bh}{h}=B 
\end{align}

Comment: How do you define the quotient of two vectors?